# My iMac (5K, 27 inch, 2019) '...restarted because of a problem'. Every time it restarted it would return to this screen, stuck in a loop

Tags: imac, memory, crash, kernel-panic, restart

My iMac was working perfectly fine (as far as I could tell) on Saturday night. I turned it on Sunday morning to be met with a slow load time, and eventually a black screen saying "Your computer restarted because of a problem. Press any key or wait a few seconds to continue starting up.". No error code/message given. Upon continuing to start up, it would load for 5-10 minutes and then return to this screen. I left it doing this all day as I had to go to work, and by the time I was back it was still doing this.

I unplugged my computer from the power cable and removed all external drives and left it for an hour. I tried launching in Recovery mode and ran first aid on each drive/volume etc. No problems were found and it ran first aid succesfully each time. I restarted my computer and again became stuck in the same loop with my computer repeatedly returning to the forementioned error screen. I then attempted to launch in safe mode which didn't seem to do anything as again I returned to that loop. I was able to launch Apple Diagnostics over the internet and ran the process, again finding no issues. I found I was able to launch my windows partition but could not launch my macOS despite seeing it as an option when choosing a drive to launch from. I also tried cleaning out all the dust from the ventilation at the bottom.

What eventually worked was removing all of the RAM I'd installed over a year ago and replacing it with the original two 4gb sticks that came with the computer (I had upgraded to 4x 16gb Crucial sticks of RAM). My computer took ages to load but it did eventually turn on and allow me to sign in. I was then met with this error message which I sent to apple:

```
panic(cpu 5 caller 0xffffff8011d31941): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from configd
service returned not alive with context : unresponsive dispatch queue(s): com.apple.main-thread 
service: logd, total successful checkins in 186 seconds: 19, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: opendirectoryd, total successful checkins in 186 seconds: 18, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: configd, no successful checkins in 186 seconds

Panicked task 0xffffff97162e8620: 4 threads: pid 111: watchdogd
Backtrace (CPU 5), panicked thread: 0xffffff9be0cbf0c8, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffb8bcdd7590 : 0xffffff800e9eb38d 
0xffffffb8bcdd75e0 : 0xffffff800eb58ed6 
0xffffffb8bcdd7620 : 0xffffff800eb48120 
0xffffffb8bcdd7670 : 0xffffff800e985951 
0xffffffb8bcdd7690 : 0xffffff800e9eb66d 
0xffffffb8bcdd7780 : 0xffffff800e9ead19 
0xffffffb8bcdd77e0 : 0xffffff800f1e07f3 
0xffffffb8bcdd78d0 : 0xffffff8011d31941 
0xffffffb8bcdd78e0 : 0xffffff8011d315e0 
0xffffffb8bcdd7900 : 0xffffff8011d306c9 
0xffffffb8bcdd7a30 : 0xffffff800f153d4a 
0xffffffb8bcdd7b90 : 0xffffff800eaffb29 
0xffffffb8bcdd7ca0 : 0xffffff800e9c2c99 
0xffffffb8bcdd7d50 : 0xffffff800e9dbbd2 
0xffffffb8bcdd7dc0 : 0xffffff800e9dc2da 
0xffffffb8bcdd7ef0 : 0xffffff800eb2a71a 
0xffffffb8bcdd7fa0 : 0xffffff800e985db6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[A0D45B98-9CEC-33FB-8E19-3AEBEC002241]@0xffffff8011d2f000->0xffffff8011d31fff

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff9be0cbf0c8): watchdogd

Mac OS version:
22D68

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 22.3.0: Mon Jan 30 20:42:11 PST 2023; root:xnu-8792.81.3~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 10E5D254-4A37-3A2A-B560-E6956A093ADE
roots installed: 0
KernelCache slide: 0x000000000e600000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff800e800000
Kernel slide:      0x000000000e6dc000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff800e8dc000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800e700000
System model name: iMac19,1 (Mac-AA95B1DDAB278B95)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 186352537405
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x0000002b637a188a
  Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
  Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x00000010f0eab20e 0x0000000000000000
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff90a8ba9000 - 0xffffffb0a8ba9000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff90a8ba9000 - 0xffffff90b0baa000
  . VM    : 0xffffff90b0baa000 - 0xffffff957c543000
  . RO    : 0xffffff957c543000 - 0xffffff9715876000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff9715876000 - 0xffffff9be120f000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff9be120f000 - 0xffffffa0acba8000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffffa0acba8000 - 0xffffffa578541000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffffa578541000 - 0xffffffaa43edb000
  . DATA  : 0xffffffaa43edb000 - 0xffffffb0a8ba9000
  Metadata: 0xffffff9050b99000 - 0xffffff9070b99000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffff9070b99000 - 0xffffff9088b99000

last started kext at 1628558110: >usb.cdc   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff8010222000, size 8192)
loaded kexts:
>BCMWLANFirmware4388.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   627.40.1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
>!ASDXC 3.3.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@filesystems.apfs   2142.81.1
>!AAHCIPort 370
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AUserConsent  1
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    403
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.Compression    1
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  334.0.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ASyntheticGame!C  10.4.1
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IO80211!F  1200.13.0
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
|IOSerial!F 11
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  345
|IOAHCI!F   301
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1110.13
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  547
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  232
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  476.81.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  476.81.2
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   5.0.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Can anybody tell me what went wrong? I'm apprehensive to reinstall all of my ram in case this causes another issue, at least until I've finished fully backing up my iMac.

Thanks!

Comment: A memory stick most likely went bad. You can find out which one by putting the memory back one stick at a time. Before you do that though, take one known good stick (the memory you have now) and test every RAM slot so you know those are good first. Once you find the bad RAM module(s), replace them

Comment: When I had RAM problems, I used memtest 4.2 (maybe gone from the web), but this should do https://memtest.org. Create a bootable USB stick.  But this doesn't avoid swapping RAM modules as @Allan suggests. Does give you documented results (take photo of screen) of RAM with errors.